# Using dependent shared libraries in eclipse plugin without requiring the LD_LIBRARY_PATH to be set with the path of dependent libraries

Tags: eclipse, plugins, unsatisfiedlinkerror

Currently i am stuck with using dependent shared libraries in eclipse plugins.

**Problem description:**
My plugin project requires libA.so that depends on libB.so. I kept both libraries under /libs of my project and included **Bundle-NativeCode: libs/  libA.so; libs/libB.so** in MANIFEST.MF file. I am loading both libraries using System.loadLibrary(). But while running the plugin, it shows the following error **"java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError": libB.SO cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory**

---

**One work-around to make it work:**
In Run/Debug settings of the application, setting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable to the absolute path of /libs folder 
But this solution wont help when i export and deploy the plugin in some other machine.

Any little guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The examples I have seen give an absolute path to each library, which is interpreted with respect to a virtual file system defined by the jar.  So, `Bundle-NativeCode: /libs/libA.so; /libs/libB.so`.  I don't have actual experience with this myself, though.

Comment: Note also that the manifest entry you posted has a space between `libs/` and `libA.so`.  If that's an accurate representation of your actual manifest then it is very likely to be a problem.